# first Mini dsp Project using matlab and books

Tags: signal, matlab, fft

i have basic knowledge of matlab and took signal and system course. i want to do project like below.
but dont know filter on matlab.
are there any books i can learn fft commands etc.(dft, filter,signal system projects).

i skimmed lot of dsp books but they have just theoretical information and not practical.

[image]

Comment: I swear this is a duplicate from a week or two ago, but can't find the original question.

Comment: As this exercise is probably exploring your understanding of the theory, you'll probably have to go back to those DSP books. The assignment specification still has the same spelling error in it...

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/141440/dsp-project-separete-voices-which-book#comment286615_141440  Edit that question instead of starting a new one. It's only on hold until you make a better question out of it, not deleted.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a book called "**DSP first**" it explains practical DSP with examples using matlab

[http://www.amazon.com/DSP-First-A-Multimedia-Approach/dp/0132431718](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132431718)

Answer (score 2):

Help should start at home.  You have plenty of tools at your fingertips

Seriously, one of your best tools will be the matlab help system.  "help filter", or if that isn't enough, "doc filter"  should yield tons of good information.

If you go into the documentation, you will also see a "getting started" guide for the signals toolbox.  If you type "help signal", you get

```
>> help signal
  Signal Processing Toolbox 
  Version 6.17 (R2012a) 29-Dec-2011 

  Table of Contents (T0C)
  -----------------------
    Digital Filters              - Digital filter design, simulation, and analysis
    Analog Filters               - Analog filter design, frequency transformation, analysis, and discretization
    Linear Systems               - Conversion of linear system representations
    Windows                      - Family of functions to window data
    Transforms                   - CZT, FFT, DCT, Goertzel, Hilbert, FWHT etc.
    Measurements and Statistics  - Signal measurements
    Cepstral Analysis            - Real, complex and inverse cepstrum
    Statistical Signal Processing- Statistical signal processing and spectral analysis
    Parametric Modeling          - AR, ARMA, and frequency response fit modeling
    Linear Prediction            - Schur, Levinson, LPC, etc.
    Multirate Signal Processing  - Interpolation, decimation, and resampling
    Waveform Generation          - Pulses, periodic and aperiodic signals, vco, etc. 
    Specialized Operations       - Plotting, vector manipulation, uniform encoding/decoding, etc.
    Graphical User Interfaces    - GUIs for data visualization, spectral analysis, filter design, and window design
    Demos                        - Signal Processing Toolbox demos

  See also audiovideo, dsp.
```